# Invoke AJAX HoverMenuExtender from Javascript in .NET

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax

In my c# web app,

I'm trying to invoke an Ajax HoverMenuExtender from Javascript, rather than from hovering over an assigned control.

If I set the TargetControlID of the HoverMenuExtender to a control on my page and hover the mouse over it, the hover menu displays, however, I cannot get it to display by manually invoking it with javascript.

The Javascript I'm currently trying:

```
popup = $("body").find('HME1');
popup.show();
//popup._popupBehavior.show();
```

I've stepped through the code so I'm sure popup.show() is being called. But it seems like nothing happens. It seems like .Show isn't really what we want to do, but instead we need to "Invoke" the AjaxExtender somehow.

The HoverMenuExtender:

```
<cc1:HoverMenuExtender ID="HME1" runat="server"  BehaviorID="HME1" TargetControlID="dummyLink" PopupPosition="Top" PopupControlID="PopupMenu"></cc1:HoverMenuExtender>
```

A dummy link i'm assigning the control ID to:

```
<a href="#" style="display:none;visibility:hidden;" onclick="return false" ID="dummyLink" runat="server">dummy</a>
```

The panel i'm trying to display:

```
<asp:Panel CssClass="popupMenu" ID="PopupMenu" 
    runat="server">
    <asp:LinkButton ID="article" runat="server" 
        CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
    <br />
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" 
        CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" />
</asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code:

$find("BehaviourID")._popupBehavior.show();

Comment: This does work. Thank you! At first it was working for me because of CSS issues.